# Create sequential requests with Coroutines kotlin

Tags: android, kotlin-coroutines

I am new in Coroutines and i have the following problem.

I have a File which is splitted in pieces and converted to mMessage objects, so i have an List.

I want to send each item in my server with a Volley request sequentially. Thuw i want to send the 1st, onSuccess send the 2nd, onSuccess send the 3rd and so on....! If one fails i have to send it again to procceed.

My question is, is there any way to do it with Kotlin Coroutines and is there any specific function that create sequential jobs or something..?

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

By default, all suspending functions run sequentially without blocking main thread.
You can write your code something like below, you build on this and add exception handling

```
suspend fun send(mMessage: Message) { // send to server }

val msgs = listOf<Messages>(...)

// send msgs one by one in asynchronous fashion
suspend fun sendAll() {
  for(msg in msgs) {
    send(msg)
  }
}
```

Comment: Thank you my friend. I finally used Retrofit that supports suspended requests. So i made a for loop creating a request in every loop...!!